# Sprout Forms `onSaveEntry` event

Tags: events, plugin-sproutforms

I need to add an event handler for the `onSaveEntry` event in order to integrate with another system. In the admin screens for the form where and how do I add this event handler?

Comment: Can you confirm what type of action you need to perform on the `onSaveEntry` Event? In the case you are trying to trigger a notification email, Sprout Forms integrates with Sprout Email allowing notifications to be sent on the `sproutForms.onSaveEntry` Event.

Comment: I need to integrate it with another system, so was planing to use an API to update the external system once a form has been saved.

Answer (score 4):

Adding an event handler is not something you do through the control panel.

What you need to do is create a [plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction) ([pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/) makes this fairly easy), and in your plugin's main class, you have an `init()` function that looks like this:

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('sproutForms.onSaveEntry', function (Event $event) {
        $entry = $event->params['entry']; // fetch the new entry
        ... do things with $entry ...
    });
}
```

If you structure your plugin properly, you will "do things with `$entry`" by calling a [Service](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/services).